# Оптимизация запроса MySQL с использованием JOIN

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, оптимизация-запросов

Есть такой запрос на `MySql`. В нем привязка трех таблиц.
На сервере оно длится несколько минут.

Индекси поставлены в таблицах.

Можете подсказать как можно изменить или оптимизировать запрос?

Вот сам запрос:

```
SELECT 
  o.name,
  a.creation_date AS a_created_at,
  o.id AS o_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT om.id) AS members,
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) AS activities 
FROM
  `organizations` AS o 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `organization_members` AS om 
    ON o.id = om.organization_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `activities` AS a 
    ON o.id = a.organization_id 
WHERE 1 
  AND o.deleted = 0 
  AND o.portal_id = 4579009354941859029 
GROUP BY o_id 
LIMIT 20;
```

А вот таблицы с индексами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вопросе об оптимизации следует давать: DDL всех таблиц (SHOW CREATE TABLE), полный текст запроса и подробное объяснение его цели и логики, план запроса на реальном массиве данных, крайне желательны сведения о статистике, особенно по значимым индексам, и основные сведения о настройках сервера (у как минимум версия). А фотографии удалите - они нафиг никому не нужны.

Comment: Да, сразу - откорректируйте запрос под ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.